# Databricks job creator details in job run

Tags: databricks, azure-databricks, job-scheduling, databricks-workflows

- User A promoted databricks pipeline in PROD using rest API.
- User B configured external orchestration tool to trigger job using REST API.
- User C uses the Databricks Jobs UI to take "Owner" privileges.

when the job are triggered, which user will be displayed as creator ? USER A or B or C ?

pls explain which user and what would be the reason.

Answer (score 0):

Creator always will be user A (until it's deleted later). You can find description in the [Jobs REST API documentation](https://docs.databricks.com/dev-tools/api/latest/jobs.html#operation/JobsGet).